# How to Livestream camera using sony sdk api

Tags: c++, image-processing, live-streaming, sony-camera-api, liveview

Im implementing a program to control sony camera attached to a robot.
As of now Ive build application to control camera settings such as shutter speed,ISO, Aperture etc.

Now i want to live stream the video on my remote controller.

As a first step when i try to use **getLiveview** API provided by sony sdk, its just taking an image and saving as a jpeg file in current directory. **Is there someway using which i can collect live stream from the camera using sony sdk?**

Comment: what about using opencv ?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code so no .jpg file is written to a file. Use a jpg decoder to send it to a framebuffer instead and, after this is completed, request an image again. Not ideal, but should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).